# Extract the higher number of a folder name in bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder with the following structure:

```
$ ls
DRS-1.1.0  DRS-1.3.0 DRS-1.3.1 DRS-1.3.2
```

with time, the folder version will increase (e.g. `DRS-1.3.5`, `DRS-1.4.1`, etc...)

How can I store the name of the highest version into a variable? (in the current case `DRS-1.3.5`)

the output should be:

```
$ echo $VERSION
DRS-1.3.2
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably easier to have whoever is adding the folders to maintain a symlink named `current` to the most recently added folder (assuming versions are added in monotonically increasing order).

Comment: @chepner: Actually, that is an excellent approach,  as it gives me much more flexibility. Also easy to implement maintain as the version will not change more than twice a year. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sort's version sort:

```
printf '%s\n' DRS-* | sort -V | tail -n 1
```

Output:

```
DRS-1.3.2
```

Comment: A reversed sort filtered through `head` would be a little more efficient than `tail` here.  Whether you could measure the difference on a modern system is debatable, though...

Comment: @TobySpeight: really? how so?

Comment: @jorgehumberto: `tail` needs to read through all the input, maintaining a buffer of the last _n_ (1 in this case) lines.  `head` just needs to copy first _n_ lines to its output and then exit, without even reading the rest of the input.  (The sort doesn't care whether it's ascending or descending - that should make no difference to its execution).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to get the max number:

```
ver=$(printf '%s\n' DRS-* | awk -F- '$2 > max{max=$2; f=$0} END{print f}')

echo "$ver"
```

```
DRS-1.3.2
```

Comment: I must say that I like the `awk`approach just because it uses `awk`. thanks!

Comment: Yes advantage is that `awk` does all in a single command instead of invoking multiple piped commands.

Answer (score 2):

Bash sorts its glob expansions alphabetically, so we can just index the last element of such an expansion:

```
files=(*)
VERSION=${files[$((${#files[*]}-1))]}
printf '%s\n' "$VERSION"
```

This has an advantage over methods that rely on filtering line-based output in that it will work all filenames, even if they include newline characters.

The downside is that it's limited to collation ordering, and doesn't understand version numbers in the way that (say) `dpkg --compare-versions` does; that will require iterating through the array, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
shopt -s nullglob

files=(DRS-*)
max=
for f in "${files[@]}"
do
    dpkg --compare-versions "${f#DRS-}" gt "${max#DRS-}" || continue
    max=$f
done

printf '%s\n' "$max"
```

(which still works with filenames containing newlines, of course)

#### Demo:

```
$ ls -1 DRS-*
DRS-1.1.0
DRS-1.12.0
DRS-1.3.0
DRS-1.3.1
DRS-1.3.2
$ ./find_max
DRS-1.12.0
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the detailed explanation.Thanks!